# Force dialogue box to foreground even when Mathematica is minimized

Tags: dialog-window

*Is there a way to make dialogue boxes to come to the foreground, on top of any other non-Mathematica windows,* *even when Mathematica itself in running in a  minimized background window*?

I am using Windows 10.

[I would like to incorporate this feature into a program to randomly poll me with survey questions, some of which are time sensitive (like "*Are you daydreaming?*", "a*re you productive at this instant?*") and some of which aren't as much ("*did you exercise in the last 24-hours?*").  If I'm using some non-mathematica application the dialogue box just appears hidden  in the background, ruining the time-sensitive questions.]